# plone 4 mySQL display

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 4.3 and I would like to connect to a MySQL database and display the results of a query in a webpage.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: This question is perfectly clear within the context of Plone. Please reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some years ago I developed an add on for doing exactly that thing:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redturtle.sqlcontents

It uses sqlalchemy.
You may want to include in your buildout MySQL-python.

Read the package documentation with attention: it stresses out some important remark about security.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  i managed to get it installed and working (sort of) but whenever i try to run a query the webpage fails to load and commands i run in the shell are delayed by a considerable amount. is this a config error on my part, or is it just because plone doesn't natively run on MySQL?

Comment: That package adds support for every DB sqlalchemy is able to handle, so MySQL should not be a problem at all. It is hard to debug what is happening without additional infos, in particular it is not clear to me what "the page fails to load" mean. Regarding the slowness, you may want to do some optimizations to the package.

Comment: I think the issue may lay in my firewall. going to try forward the port MySQL runs on and see if that fixes it.